# How to deal with common properties in NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, properties, mapping

I'm learning NHibernate, when I defined an abstract class named "EntityBase":

```
public abstract class EntityBase
{
    public EntityBase()
    {
        CreateTime = DateTime.Now;
        IsDelete = false;
    }
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime CreateTime { get; protected set; }

    public virtual bool IsDelete { get; set; }

    public virtual int Version { get; protected set; }
}
```

Some sub-class like these:

```
public class Role : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Department : EntityBase, IAggregateRoot
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I would write a lot of *.hbm.xml files below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="LY.OA.Model.Authority" assembly="LY.OA.Model">
      <class name="Role" table="T_Role" lazy="false">
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
  <generator class="native"></generator>
</id>
<property name="Name">
  <column name="RoleName" sql-type="varchar(30)" not-null="true"></column>
</property>

<bag name="Users" table="T_UserRole" inverse="true" cascade="all" lazy="true">
  <key column="RoleId"></key>
  <many-to-many class="User" column="UserId"/>
</bag>

<!--Common properties-->
<property name="Description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="String"/>
<property name="CreateTime" column="CREATETIME" type="DateTime"/>
<property name="IsDelete" column="ISDELETE" type="Boolean"/>
<property name="Version" column="VERSION" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="LY.OA.Model.Authority"   assembly="LY.OA.Model">
  <class name="Department" table="T_Department" lazy="false">
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="int">
      <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
<property name="Name">
  <column name="DepartmentName" sql-type="varchar(30)" not-null="true"></column>
</property>

<!--Common properties-->
<property name="Description" column="DESCRIPTION" type="String"/>
<property name="CreateTime" column="CREATETIME" type="DateTime"/>
<property name="IsDelete" column="ISDELETE" type="Boolean"/>
<property name="Version" column="VERSION" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

However, I won't write such boring common properties in each xml, but where could I place these common properties in a file so that each mapping file can reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you with "common properties" mean the properties in your base class? There are different strategies to map inheritance in NH. Read more here...
http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

It's easy with Fluent NHibernate and I encourage to use that instead of XML mappings. If you're stuck with XML, see [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140521/nhibernate-not-fluent-nh-is-it-possible-to-reuse-components/3140673#3140673).